# Dispatch mutations from service file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have an `ApiService()` that I'm abstracting my API calls into. I'd like to
`dispatch('SET_BUSY')` and `dispatch('SET_NOT_BUSY')` app-level mutations from within the
service, but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: dispatch is not a function. (In 'dispatch('SET_BUSY')', 'dispatch' is undefined)
```

---

**/vuex/actions.js**

```
import { ApiService } from './services';

export const setAppMode = function ({ dispatch }) {
  ApiService({
    noun: 'Application',
    verb: 'GetMode'
  }, response => {
    dispatch('SET_APP_MODE', response.Data.mode);
  },
  dispatch);
};
```

**/vuex/services.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';

export const ApiService = (options = {}, callback, dispatch) => {
  let endpoint = 'localhost/api/index.php';
  let parameters = options.data;

  dispatch('SET_BUSY');

  Vue.http.post(endpoint, parameters, []).then((promise) => {
    return promise.text();
  }, (promise) => {
    return promise.text();
  }).then(response => {
    response = JSON.parse(response);

    dispatch('SET_NOT_BUSY');

    if (response.Result === 'ERROR') {
      console.log('ERROR: ' + response.Error.Message);
    }

    callback(response);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An action function expects the **store** instance as the first parameter. This is usually done by Vuex automatically.

When using an action in a Vue instance, the way to accomplish it in Vuex 1 is as follows:

```
import { setAppMode } from './actions'

new Vue({
  vuex: {
    actions: {
      setAppMode
    }
  }
})
```

Now you can use `this.setAppMode()` and have the store automatically available as first argument.

Note: you also need to set the `store`property of the VM

```
import store from `./store`

// and inside the VM options:
{ 
    store: store
}
```

If `store` has not been set to the vm instance, you still can pass it as a parameter, manually:

```
this.setAppMode(store);
```

Comment: `"vue": "^1.0.21"` and `"vuex": "^1.0.0-rc.2"`. I have an action called `setAppMode()` which I import into the `App.vue` component and reference by `this.setAppMode()`.

Comment: Maybe you added `setAppMode` to the `methods` of the vm... You should use `vuex` instead. I've added more information to the answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're after. Yes, that is the method I used to import and use it inside `App.vue`, which works (aside from the dispatch thing).

Comment: Passing the `store` object into the service did the trick. Leave it as an answer and I'll gladly accept it!

Comment: I edited it once more. Hopefully, it is better than before.

Comment: Oh. Why yes indeed. ;)